# Packaging Python stub files (*.pyi) in a module

Tags: python, python-3.7, visual-studio-code, python-packaging

I am trying to create a Python package with *.pyi stub files but my editor, VS Code, is ignoring my efforts. It isn't clear to me how to properly create a Python package with stubs.

The root dir of my package contains these files:

```
__init__.py
__init__.pyi
py.typed
```

I am including `py.typed` in the `setup.py` package_data and when I build and install the package I see all of those files are in fact installed by pip. But when I restart VS Code and test, the code completion looks the same as before. I've read through [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#storing-and-distributing-stub-files) and [PEP 561](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information) and I don't see what I am missing.

I know from other StackOverflow threads that I need to make sure Jedi is turned off and am using Microsoft's IntelliCode functionality. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use Jedi? It does support type hints now.

Comment: That's great but I need to make a project that works properly, regardless of whether or not other people use Jedi.

Comment: Simply search the web for vscode and pyi and you will learn the *native* support for it is non existent or patchy https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1126